# Is there a way to configure "Settings -> Personalization -> Taskbar -> Turn system icons on or off" programmatically?

Tags: windows, api, winapi, operating-system, trayicon

I'd like to configure windows settings using Win32 API.
Main purpose is to hide system tray icon from taskbar, such as Network Status icon, Volume icon and Audio Recording icon).
I tried using `Shell_NotifyIconW()`, but it can hide "Users"'s icons not system icons.
I'd like to use VS2017 + on Windows 10 (x64).
Let someone please help me to solve this issue.
[image]

Comment: There is no api for this. You configure this through the GUI.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no winapi to turn system icons on or off. I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1535485/programmatically-open-turn-system-icons-on-or-off-in-a-similar-way-to-cortana

Comment: There's no API by design, only the end-user can do this, but you can automate it using something like UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32 (or other automating tools).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there is no winapi to turn system icons on or off. I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1535485/programmatically-open-turn-system-icons-on-or-off-in-a-similar-way-to-cortana

And as Simon said, you could also try to use UI Automation.